# IOS App getting killed immediately after entering background

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Hi my app is getting killed immediately after entering background i.e when user press home button and starts to use other apps.

From Apple Developer Documentation site I found these

> Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should not wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks. System-initiated termination is a normal part of an app’s life cycle. The system usually terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and make room for other apps being launched by the user, but the system may also terminate apps that are misbehaving or not responding to events in a timely manner.

From the Apple site it is clear that under memory pressure my app will be terminated. So what I did is I used Leak in instrument to fix all memory leaks in my app and also made sure that `-(void)dealloc` is called in all View Controllers.

[image: Remaining Leaks]

Now the remaining leaks are because of system frameworks like foundation and core foundation, which I cannot fix.

Even after fixing memory leaks my app is getting killed within 10-20 seconds after entering background.

Currently my app use 100 MB of memory.

1. So is there any tool that I can use to find out which objects use how much of memory.
2. Is there any memory benchmarking tool available that helps me to find how my app is improved from my previous version in terms of memory handling.
3. What are the things that I have to do, so as to make my app to live for more time in the background mode.

Comment: From what you are saying seems like app enters suspended state and not gets terminated. Looks like you are confused between suspended state and termination. Clarify that first. If app is suspended and if you wanna keep it alive for long opt for background modes

Comment: My issue is app enters suspended state and it gets terminated Immediately. I don't want to opt for background modes since I'm not going to execute any code in background. Facebook (Youtube, Whatsapp ..etc) app can remain in suspended state for like 1 hour and still able to take the user to where he left without restarting the app. This is the behaviour I want in my app.

Comment: Thats strange considering you are not leaving any memory leaks in your app. Sounds interesting, unfortunately I dont know the solution for, Ill keep a watch :) +1